# USB devices returns kIOReturnExclusiveAccess replug on Max OS 10.13.4

Tags: macos, usb

I have been unable to figure out why the call UsbDeviceOpen() returns kIOReturnExclusiveAccess after I unplug and replug.

Design:
1. On thread running the CFRunLoop() that detects the adds/removes of devices
2. 2nd Thread that does the Async reads and writes.

When thread 1 receives the kIOMessageServiceIsTerminated event,
I AbortPipe(), USBInterfaceClose(), Interface->Release(), USBDeviceClose(), DeviceInterface->Release() and IOObectRelease(notification).

All calls returns kIOReturnSuccess except the USBDeviceClose().  It returns kIOReturnNoDevice.  This makes sense because the device has been removed.  But when I replug, the OS still seems to think a thread/task/process has the device open.  On a very rare occasion, the replug will work.

I am relatively new to programming on a Mac, and I have found their documentation to be lacking.  If someone can suggest a Mac specific forum, that would be great.  This is a programming issue not a system/general user problem.

Thank you,
Jim

Comment: The use of threads adds a layer of complexity that could conceivably cause all sorts of problems.  If you can reduce your code down to a single-threaded [mcve] that reproduces the problem while throwing out everything that isn't needed, that might help.  Alternatively, you might try replacing your low-level USB code with calls to this single-threaded USB abstraction library that works on macOS to see if the same problem still happens: https://github.com/pololu/libusbp (I wrote it).  There's also a mailing list:  https://lists.apple.com/mailman/listinfo/usb

Comment: I think I resolved my issue but I cannot tell you why.  I don't think Apple appreciates us C coders writing low level IOKit code.  Anyway.. If you are familiar with the USB sample provided by Apple, this will make sense.  When a device is plugged in the DeviceAdded() routine is called.  This is where I was opening the USB Device (USBDeviceOpen).  I was not closing it until the device was removed physically.  If I close the USB device (USBDeviceClose) after I set the configuration, and just use the interface to communicate with, all is well.

Comment: I think I do not have a good  grasp how Mac relates DeviceInterface and InterfaceInterface.  I do not need to have the device opened, to communicate with the Bulk endpoints, I just need the Interface opened.